# wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code {0} django html to pdf on server

Tags: python, django, wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf

I am converting html to pdf using wkhtmltopdf.
But I am getting an error

```
raise IOError("wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code {0}. error:\n{1}".format(exit_code, stderr.decode("utf-8")))
IOError: wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code 1. error:
xvfb-run: error: Xvfb failed to start
```

My code is:

```
    f = open('cover_page.html', 'w')
    cap_type = indi_user.cap_type
    message = """<html>
    <head></head>
    <body><h1 style="font-size:150px;margin-top: 450px;">%s</h1></body>
    </html>""" % (cap_type.encode('utf-8').strip())
    f.write(message)
    f.close()
    pdfkit.from_url('cover_page.html', 'cover_page.pdf')
    os.remove("cover_page.html")
    final_pdf_list.insert(0, 'cover_page.pdf')
    to_be_removed.append("cover_page.pdf")
    pypdftk.concat(final_pdf_list, str(destination))
```

I don't know what wrong I am doing wrong there.

I tried everything but still stuck on the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have XVFB installed ? if not  you should install it by package manager, for example `apt-get install xvfb`. Otherwise get through the /tmp/xvfb-error.log file, to get specific xvfb error message.

Answer (score 0):

wkhtmltopdf is works with the help of X graphic server. 
If we want to use it in the server then it will become a problem that means it will not works.
To make it work in the server we need to install a X server (xvfb).

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
```

Reference: https://learnbatta.com/blog/django-html-to-pdf-using-pdfkit-and-wkhtmltopdf-5/

Answer (score 0):

This problem has two solutions first, if you are an external server to create pdf using wkhtmltopdf then you can first connect this server manually using your pc.
second, you can create a file in the temp path in your local system using `pdfkit.from_string(wkhtmltopdf)` after you can move this to the external server path.
This issue occurs because of external server doesn't allow to run `wkhtmltopdf.exe`